# How to pronounce LaTeX correctly?

Tags: tex-history

I have heard the following 4 pronunciations for this word LaTeX. Which is the correct one?

1. Laatec
2. Letec
3. Laatecs
4. Letecs

Comment: #2 as in Lay-tech

Comment: Thank you for the information

Comment: Potayto, Potahto. The point about LaTeX is flexibility, so I guess all four work. Leslie Lamport, LaTeX creator, isn't fussed: "language is not always logical".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LaTeX):

> LaTeX (/ˈlɑːtɛx/ *LAH-tekh* or /ˈleɪtɛx/ *LAY-tekh;* a shortening of Lamport TeX) is a document preparation system. [...]

and in [a more detailed section, *Pronouncing and writing "LaTeX"*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LaTeX#Pronouncing_and_writing_%22LaTeX%22):

> [...] TeX's creator Donald Knuth promotes a pronunciation of /tɛx/ (*tekh*) (that is, with a voiceless velar fricative as in Modern Greek, similar to the ch in loch). Lamport writes "TeX is usually pronounced *tech*, making *lah*-teck, lah-*teck*, and *lay*-teck the logical choices; but language is not always logical, so *lay-tecks* is also possible." [...]

I pronounce it *lah*-teck.

Comment: So you are just one consonant away to correct TeX :)

Answer (score 3):

As you can find in [Introduction to LaTeX](https://www.latex-project.org/about/) section of the LaTeX project site:

> LaTeX, which is pronounced «Lah-tech» or «Lay-tech» (to rhyme with
>   «blech» or «Bertolt Brecht»), is a document preparation system for
>   high-quality typesetting. It is most often used for medium-to-large
>   technical or scientific documents but it can be used for almost any
>   form of publishing.

So, it is *not* pronunced with a final "x".